Is $(\mathbb{Q},0,+,<)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}^{+},1,\cdot,<)$? ("Logic in Mathematics and Set Theory" by Kazuyuki Tanaka and Toshio Suzuki)
I am reading "Logic in Mathematics and Set Theory" by Kazuyuki Tanaka and Toshio Suzuki.

Problem 1.17
Is $(\mathbb{Q},0,+,<)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}^{+},1,\cdot,<)$?

My attempt:

Assume that $F$ is isomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q},0,+,<)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}^{+},1,\cdot,<)$.
Then, $F(0)=1$.
Let $q:=F(1)\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$.
Then, $F(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{q}\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ since $q=F(1)=F(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})=F(\frac{1}{2})\cdot F(\frac{1}{2})$.
Similarly, $F(\frac{1}{n})=\sqrt[n]{q}\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$.

I guess the following proposition holds:

If $q\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ and $\sqrt[n]{q}\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ for any $n\in\{1,2,\dots\}$, then $q=1$.

But I cannot prove this proposition holds.
Please tell me the proof.
If this proposition is true, then

$F(0)=1=q=F(1)$.
This is a contradiction since $F$ is injective.


Consider the $2$-valuation of $\sqrt[n]q$. Then that of $q$ has to be divisible by all positive integers, so it must be $0$. Similarly for each prime valuation.

@ParclyTaxel thank you very much for your comment.

A positive rational number can be written uniquely
$$q=\prod_{p\in\mathcal P}p^{r(p)}$$
where $\mathcal P$ is the set of prime numbers and $r:\mathcal P\to\Bbb Z$ is of finite support (i.e. $r(p)=0$ except for finitely many values of $p$).
$\sqrt[n]q$ is then rational iff $n$ divides each exponent $r(p)$.
The only integer which is divisible by every $n\in\Bbb N$ is $0$, hence if  every
$\sqrt[n]q$ is rational
then $r$ is the zero map, i.e. $q=1$.
More abstractly: $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is a divisible group, contrarily to the free abelian group
$(\Bbb Q^+,\cdot)\cong\left(\bigoplus_{p\in\mathcal P}\Bbb Z,+\right)$.

Anne Bauvel, thank you very much for your answer.

Let $F(1)=q=\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ and $a,b\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
Let $n\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.
Then, $F(\frac{1}{n})=\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{l}{m}$ for some $l,m\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ such that $\gcd(l,m)=1$.
Then, $am^n=bl^n$.
Suppoose $a$ is divisible by $p$ for some prime number $p$.
Then, $l$ is divisible by $p$ since $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
Since $l^n$ is divisible by $p^n$ and $\gcd(l,m)=1$, $a$ is divisible by $p^n$.
$n$ was an arbitrary positive integer.
This is a contradiction.
So, $a$ must be $1$.
Similary, $b$ must be $1$.
So, $q$ must be $1$.

You can try to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{×}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of a cyclic group of order 2 and a free abelian group with countably many
generators, and $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ is not a direct sum of two proper subgroups.
(the element of $\mathbb{Q}^{×}$ has a form of $p/q$ and is devided into 2 parts by 0, and the cardinality of each part is not greater than $card((p,q))$ which is countable because $\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ is countable; but $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ has no minimal generating set)

0001晕1000 thank you very much for your answer.

you're welcome Ｏ(≧∇≦)Ｏ
